# Computing Colorfulness of an Image in Python (Fast)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, numba

I am asking this question because I have a suggestion about https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/05/computing-image-colorfulness-with-opencv-and-python/

Here, they are citing Hasler and Süsstrunk’s 2003 paper, Measuring colorfulness in natural images. They are using NumPy to perform calculations but I'm a bit concerned about the speed at which one can compute the colorfulness of an image.

#### Original Method

```py
from imutils import build_montages
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

def image_colorfulness(image):
    # split the image into its respective RGB components
    (B, G, R) = cv2.split(image.astype("float"))
    # compute rg = R - G
    rg = np.absolute(R - G)
    # compute yb = 0.5 * (R + G) - B
    yb = np.absolute(0.5 * (R + G) - B)
    # compute the mean and standard deviation of both `rg` and `yb`
    (rbMean, rbStd) = (np.mean(rg), np.std(rg))
    (ybMean, ybStd) = (np.mean(yb), np.std(yb))
    # combine the mean and standard deviations
    stdRoot = np.sqrt((rbStd ** 2) + (ybStd ** 2))
    meanRoot = np.sqrt((rbMean ** 2) + (ybMean ** 2))
    # derive the "colorfulness" metric and return it
    return stdRoot + (0.3 * meanRoot)
```

Comment: In python, NumPy is going to be the quickest way to compute that. If you want faster use OpenCV and C++

Comment: I would recommend **against** C++. if you need (pure) python code to be faster than comparable numpy or other library code, use numba. that'll use LLVM to great effect.

Comment: present a [mre], then we can play "code golf". linking to an off-site resource is no fun. I have no desire to improve upon anything posted on that particular blog. it's a great resource to impress beginners but a substandard teaching resource.

Comment: There is no real question here. If you have some code, and potential concerns on its speed, please provide the code in the form of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and point to the details that concern you. The question, as is, should not be in SO.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I agree, do you have any hardcore computer vision courses or resources to recommend.

Comment: if I felt like raking in the adsense bucks, I'd write my own blog ;) don't have the time though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a try at speeding this up, just by using **OpenCV** functions and got a 6.5x speed-up over your **Numba** version on my machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import cv2
from numba import *

def me(image,B,G,R):
    # Use OpenCV methods wherever possible
    rg = cv2.absdiff(R,G)
    rgMean, rgStd  = cv2.meanStdDev(rg)

    avg = cv2.addWeighted(R, 0.5, G, 0.5, 0)
    yb  = cv2.absdiff(avg, B)
    ybMean, ybStd  = cv2.meanStdDev(yb)

    # combine the mean and standard deviations
    stdRoot = np.sqrt((rgStd ** 2) + (ybStd ** 2))
    meanRoot = np.sqrt((rgMean ** 2) + (ybMean ** 2))
    # derive the "colorfulness" metric and return it
    return stdRoot + (0.3 * meanRoot), rgMean, rgStd, ybMean, ybStd

@njit(parallel=True)
def image_colorfulness(image,B,G,R):
    # compute rg = R - G
    rg = np.absolute(R - G)
    # compute yb = 0.5 * (R + G) - B
    yb = np.absolute(0.5 * (R + G) - B)
    # compute the mean and standard deviation of both `rg` and `yb`
    rgMean, rgStd = np.mean(rg), np.std(rg)
    ybMean, ybStd = np.mean(yb), np.std(yb)
    # combine the mean and standard deviations
    stdRoot = np.sqrt((rgStd ** 2) + (ybStd ** 2))
    meanRoot = np.sqrt((rgMean ** 2) + (ybMean ** 2))
    # derive the "colorfulness" metric and return it
    return stdRoot + (0.3 * meanRoot), rgMean, rgStd, ybMean, ybStd


image   = cv2.imread('Oscars-selfie_620x349.png')

# OP's original method
B, G, R = cv2.split(image.astype("float"))
score, *others   = image_colorfulness(image,B=B,G=G,R=R)
print(score, others)

%timeit image_colorfulness(image,B=B,G=G,R=R)

# Using OpenCV and avoiding promotion to float
B, G, R = cv2.split(image)
score, *others   = me(image,B=B,G=G,R=R)
print(score, others)

%timeit  me(image,B=B,G=G,R=R)
```

**Timings for original and OpenCV methods**

```
1.11 ms ± 43.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

171 µs ± 1.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: In all fairness, it should be mentioned that the Numba approach is less than memorable. If you avoid conversion to float, also with a pure NumPy approach you would get better timing than OP's. A Numba-optimized version (with spelled-out loops, combined mean/std computation, and with minimal type casting) is probably going to be in the same ballpark as the `cv`-optimized one, although probably not as fast as the `cv`-optimized one, at least for larger images.